# How to determine from a python application if X server/X forwarding is running?

Tags: python, ssh, pyqt4, xserver

I'm writing a linux application which uses PyQt4 for GUI and which will only be used during remote sessions 
(*ssh -XY* / *vnc*).

So sometimes it may occur that a user will forget to run *ssh* with X forwarding parameters or X forwarding will be unavailable for some reason. In this case the application crashes badly (unfortunately I am force to use an old C++ library wrapped into python and it completely messes user's current session if the application crashes).

I cannot use something else so my idea is to check if X forwarding is available before loading that library. However I have no idea how to do that.

I usually use xclock to check if my session has X forwarding enabled, but using xclock sounds like a big workaround.

**ADDED**
If possible I would like to use another way than creating an empty PyQt window and catching an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check to see that the `$DISPLAY` environment variable is set - if they didn't use `ssh -X`, it will be empty (instead of containing something like `localhost:10`).

Comment: That's examply what I was looking for, clean and simple, thanks.

Comment: What happens if they use `ssh -X` but have no X server running? From my casual testing it seems that `$DISPLAY` won't be set, but is that reliably true?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned before, you can check the DISPLAY environment variable:

```
>>> os.environ['DISPLAY']
'localhost:10.0'
```

If you're so inclined, you could actually connect to the display port to see that sshd is listening on it:

```
import os
import socket

def tcp_connect_to_display():
        # get the display from the environment
        display_env = os.environ['DISPLAY']

        # parse the display string
        display_host, display_num = display_env.split(':')
        display_num_major, display_num_minor = display_num.split('.')

        # calculate the port number
        display_port = 6000 + int(display_num_major)

        # attempt a TCP connection
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
                sock.connect((display_host, display_port))
        except socket.error:
                return False
        finally:
            sock.close()
        return True
```

This relies on standard X configuration using ports 6000 + display number.

Comment: I will remember this solution, maybe it will prove useful in the future thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your xclock solution, I like to run xdpyinfo and see if it returns an error.

Comment: This is great as it exits with zero if the client hasn't got a X-server running (a common thing for windows users who forget to start xming).
I'm going to use this in a bash script, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

X-Server can be checked with *TkInter* as in the following example (but there should be a similar way with *PyQt4*):

```
import time
import sys
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

while True:
    try:
        root = tk.Tk()
        break
    except tk.TclError as e:
        if "$DISPLAY" in str(e):
            print("$DISPLAY not set. Exiting.")
            sys.exit(1)
        print("Waiting for X server to start...")
        time.sleep(1)

print("X server running")
root.destroy()
sys.exit(0)
```

This will check `$DISPLAY` setting, X-Server process and related `xhost` authorization (but uses *TkInter* instead of *PyQt4*).